# Is$ \langle G,+\rangle$ a sub-group of $\langle F,+\rangle$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, functions, normal-subgroups

> Let $F$ be the set of all real-valued functions with domain $\Bbb R$ and let $F^{1}$ be the subset of $F$ consisting of those functions that have nonzero value at every point in $\Bbb R$.
>
> Let $G$ be the subset of all $f\in F^1$ such that $f(1)=1$.
>
> Is $\langle G,+\rangle$ a sub-group of $\langle F ,+\rangle$?
>
> Note that $+$ stands for addition.

I could figure out that the identity element of $\langle F,+\rangle $, i.e. $ \mathbf{O}: \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$ st. $\mathbf O(x)=0 \ \forall x\in \Bbb R$ is not present in $G$. This means that the group $\langle G,+\rangle $ is not a sub-group of $\langle F,+\rangle $.

But my solution says $\langle G,+\rangle$ is not closed in the first place. I couldn't understand how this conclusion could be arrived at.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: $f $,$ g$ be elements of $G$ . Then $f(1)=1$,$g(1)=1  $  but $(f+g)(1) = 2$ ,hence it is not closed

Comment: For $G$ to be closed under $+$, you need $-f$ to be in $G$, but this means that there's a function such that $f(1) = -1$ so $G$ is not closed.

Comment: It could very well be that they are using $+$ as the 'arbitrary' group operation and have intended for it to be multiplication (a poor choice of symbol choice, but this could be what was intended). Because $F^1$ is not even closed under $+$ taken as addition but is closed under multiplication.

Comment: Hi @mathematics2x2life thanks for your answer. I guess I should have mentioned it more explicitly that '+' stands for addition. I am making the edit in my question.

Comment: @AbhilashMishra Then as it stands the question itself is already rather terrible (not at all your fault) because $F^1$ is not even a group. Clearly, $f \equiv 1$ and $g \equiv -1$ are in $F^1$. With the operation being addition, $f+g \equiv 0$, which is not in $F^1$ even though $f,g$ are. Why would we talk about subgroups for something which itself is not even a group?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a counterexample. Take, for example, $f(x) = 1$ and $g(x) = 1 + |x - 1|$. Note that $f(1) = g(1) = 1$ and $g(x) \ge f(x) \ge 1 > 0$, so $f, g \in G$. But, $(f + g)(1) = f(1) + g(1) = 1 + 1 = 2 \neq 1$. Thus $f + g \notin G$. That is, it is possible to add two elements of $G$, but not remain in $G$, meaning $+$ is not a well-defined binary operation when restricted to $G$.

It's not that your argument was wrong, it was more that it was putting the cart before the horse. In order to talk about an identity, we really should make sure we're dealing with a well-defined operation (similarly, before discussing inverses, we must first figure out if there is an identity).

Comment: $f(1) = g(1) = 1$ edit that!!

Comment: @Rkb Yep! Thanks for pointing that out.